# MSSQL to OracleDB LinkedServer (same server!)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I need to do the following: Create a linked server between SQL Server 2012 and Oracle Database 12c. Both of the database servers are located on the same server.

How can I achieve this? I tried adding in `tnsnames.ora` a data source with the IP of the server and the SID used by the OracleDB, and used that as the `@datasrc` parameter in the `addlinkedserver` stored procedure, but it didn't work out.

Comment: This is definitely possible. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server/

Comment: @AndreyBelykh, Thank you! - That article specified that EZConnect could be used. I went on and put in the `@datasrc` `IP:PORT\Service_Name` and now I have the linked server.